# MissingControllerException directory in /app/webroot/file/

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I get these messages in my error.log:

```
Request URL: /files/thumbs1/1354046882.jpg
Stack Trace:
#0 /path/to/web/app/webroot/index.php(92):     Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2013-05-08 13:44:16 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class     FilesController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'FilesController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
```

The image file /files/thumbs1/1354046882.jpg exists and shows up. But apart from this i get the Error in the error.log.
I produce the url manualy in the view .ctp like this:

```
<img src="/files/thumbs1/1354046882.jpg" alt="">
```

I don't use 
    echo $this->Html->image('cake_logo.png', array('alt' => 'CakePHP'));

How can I add a ControllerException, so that the directory "files" in webroot is not identified as a controller. I don't have a FilesController. 
Or is it possible, that "file" is a protected word in CakePHP which shouldn't be used? Couldn't find something related in the CakeBook up to now.

The .htaccess in /webroot

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.domainname.com
   RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I updatet to CakePHP 2.3.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you producing the url that gives you that error? Can you update the question with that code?

Comment: I updated the question with the code how i produce the file.

Comment: Are you using the original `.htaccess`? Or have you made modifications to that (e.g. moved the rewrite-settings to the vhost)?

Comment: I updated the question with the .htaccess. I added to the original a rewrite rule to become www.domain.com from domain.com. I didn' modify any ohter .htaccess

Comment: @mart where you able to solve the problem? i am having the same issue with webroot/uploads/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule in your .htaccess so that request urls starting with /files/ are not routed to index.php.

On a side note try not to generate urls to missing files :)

Comment: You say the file exists still the request is routed to cakephp. That's not possible with the default rewrite rules in .htaccess. If the path `/files/thumbs1/1354046882.jpg` exists in your webroot and the file is readable by the webserver it should be served by the webserver itself.

Comment: thank you. It looks like if i have a problem with the rewrite rule somewhere, but i can't find it up to now.

Comment: Well you can replace your webroot/.htaccess file with an unmodified file from a fresh cakephp package.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood everything correctly, then your only problem is not writing the right urls.

I'm going to assume some things here: your folders' structure is something similar to

```
/app
    /Config
    /Console
    ...
    /webroot
        /files
/lib
/plugins
/vendors
```

And what you want is to show an image located in this files directory, right?

Then you need to make sure to [get your paths right](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ihari/2006/10/16/getting-your-paths-right). If you don't tell cake you want a file in your webroot, then with this type of url

```
files/something/something-else
```

cake is just going to think "ok, this path is **controller/action/params** (this is a generalization, clearly this assumption can be modified with [routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html))", and fail because **files** is not a controller.

So, to fix this, everytime you want to point to something on the webroot directory, add it to the path. In you case it should be

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>files/thumbs1/1354046882.jpg" alt="">
```

And if the file exists, it should be displayed without errors.